# CORS Issue in a MERN stack webapp

Tags: node.js, cors, passport.js

I have a MERN stack app that uses passport-Microsoft strategy in the backend for single-sign-on access to the app where I'm calling my auth route i.e,(localhost:3300/login/Microsoft) with CORS header however that API will redirect to /login/microsoft/redirect as per the passport-Microsoft strategy which is giving CORS error in preflight request. My question is I'm not calling this redirect API from the frontend whereas the backend redirects it How can I over come this cors error with this redirect API???

Note: Its working fine when I test the API alone with backend

Here is the error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest '`login.microsoftonline.com/{clientsecret}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3300%2Flogin%2FMicrosft%2Fredirect&scope=user.read&client_id={clientid}`' (redirected from '`localhost:3300/login/microsoft`') from origin '`localhost:3300`' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I don't understand -- CORS is made to restrict browser requests (once you've already loaded a web page). Usually Passport will redirect the browser, and browser redirects are not restricted by CORS, so you should not be having CORS issues. Are you trying to authenticate from within a single-page app without redirecting? Either way, add the CORS headers to `/login/microsoft/redirect`, which is a route you'll have to handle anyway, and you should be done

Comment: I have already applied the CORS policy on my backend however my redirect API in express would look something like this app.get('/auth/microsoft/callback',
  passport.authenticate('microsoft', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),} where I'm not sure how can I add cors to this particular API which in generally should rely on cors policy applied to app @Codebling

Comment: You're using Express, so did you apply the CORS policy to the entire server `.use(corsmiddleware)` or to certain routes?  Can you paste the CORS error? It doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Yes I did apply cors to the whole app like the app.use(cors()) and Here is the error :                  Access to XMLHttpRequest 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{clientsecret}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3300%2Flogin%2FMicrosft%2Fredirect&scope=user.read&client_id={clientid}' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3300/login/microsoft') from origin 'http://localhost:3300' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I've put the error in the question (you should put the error in there in the future). So the issue is not with `/login/microsoft/redirect` but with the Microsoft URL. I'll add an answer.

Comment: I've added an answer. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

I can see from this error that this is an `XMLHttpRequest`. This means you are trying to load `localhost:3300/login/microsoft` from an XHR/Ajax call from the browser. That is incorrect.

Instead of an XHR, redirect the browser page to `localhost:3300/login/microsoft`. This is how OAuth works - the browser needs to display a login page to the user and prompt them for credentials. You can't do this as an XHR /ajax call.